# Logic on total sum of input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, logic

I have created 4 input boxes with plus and minus to increase and decrease the value. I want to make a logic that as soon as the sum of all 4 values adds up to 5, it should disable the plus buttons and do not allow the user to add more.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="field1">field 1
    <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="1" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add" class="add">+</button>
</div>
<div id="field2">field 2
    <button type="button" id="sub2" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="2" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add2" class="add">+</button>
</div>

<div id="field2">field 3
    <button type="button" id="sub3" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="3" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add3" class="add">+</button>
</div>

<div id="field2">field 4
    <button type="button" id="sub4" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="text" id="4" value="0" class="field" />
    <button type="button" id="add4" class="add">+</button>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I am using to increase/decrease the values:

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);

$('.add').click(function () {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);    
});

$('.sub').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().val() > 0) $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);    
});
```

Comment: so you are going outside for play ?

Comment: @Mahi - Sorry if you got that impression, however I am honestly stuck in trying and getting errors, so I thought in asking for some help and not play outside I can assure you!

Comment: Something like: $('.add').click(function(){if($('#1').val() + $('#2').val() + $('#3').val() + $('#4').val() > 4) { $(".add").prop('disabled', true);} else { $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1); }

Comment: You could also add them using each()

Comment: @MarleyFrankey then you should have posted that code that you are facing errors .

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('.add').click(function () {
var value1 = $('#field1').find('input').val();
var value2 = $('#field2').find('input').val();
var value3 = $('#field3').find('input').val();
var value4 = $('#field4').find('input').val();
  if ( value1 + value2 + value3 + value4 >= 5){
    $('.add').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is working, however only on one input box and not the sum of the 4 input boxes.

Comment: It's also quite simple. Please check the revised version